# How to find the position vector given $3$ colinear points?

Tags: vectors

$P$, $Q$ and $R$ are $3$ collinear points in space, with position vectors $p$, $q$ and $r$ respectively. Point $Q$ lies between $P$ and $R$ such that the distance from $P$ to $Q$ is twice the distance from $Q$ to $R$.

Which of the following is true?

[image]

How can I compute this? is $PQ$ = $2QR$?

Comment: I would draw a picture and just check the different options, one by one, see which one is true. Don't worry too much about the paper being two-dimensional when it said the vectors are in space, that doesn't actually change the answer.

Comment: @Arthur Yeah, thats my problem, I was going to visualise it but couldn't since it is in 3D.

Answer (score 0):

Sketch the situation on paper as if it were in 2D. Now $ \vec r$ = $\vec{p} + \vec{PR} \:$ and $\vec{PR} = \vec{pq} + \frac{1}{2} \cdot \vec{pq}$. By writing $\vec{pq} = q - p$, you obtain: $\vec{r} = \frac{3}{2} \vec{q} - \frac{1}{2}\vec{p}$.

(Recall that $\vec{pq} = \vec q - \vec p$).

Maybe the following image clears things up:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the data given, $$Q=P+\frac 23 \vec{PR}$$
In other words $$Q=P+\frac 23(R-P)$$
so $$3Q = P + 2R$$